# Using [style.something.px]="2" to define the border width (thikness) in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Currently, I'm defining the element width with this syntax:

```
<div [style.width.px]="size" [style.height.px]="size"></div>
```

What I want is to use a similar syntax but to define the border-width css property, something like this:

```
<div [style.border-width.px]="borderSize"></div>
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You could've done something like that too: [ngStyle]="{'borderWidth.px : borderSize}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out that I could do something like this:

```
// Html
<div [style.borderWidth.px]="borderSize"></div>

// Typescript
@Component(...)
export class LoaderComponent {
    borderSize = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div [style.border-width.px]="borderSize"></div>
```

every css property which has `-` in them, need to remove the `-` and camelcase the next letter.

like:

```
[style.borderWidth.px]="size here"
[style.paddingLeft.px]="size here"
[style.marginRight.px]="size here"
```